# Examples of diagonal line segments in $\mathbb{R}^2$ that contain no rational points?

Tags: general-topology, geometry, real-numbers, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

I know we can have a vertical line , something like $(\pi, y)$ for $y$ in some interval, or a horizontal line, something like $(x, \pi)$ for $x$ in some interval, that contains no points $(q_1, q_2)$ s.t. $q_1, q_2 \in \mathbb{Q}$.

I believe that it is possible to have a (continuous, straight) diagonal line segment that has no rational points (mostly because I am unable to prove otherwise!).

Are there any examples of a line like this?

Comment: (pi,y) and (x,pi) are not lines.  They are points.

Comment: @WilliamElliot He means $\{(\pi,y):y\in\Bbb R\}$ and $\{(x,\pi):x\in\Bbb R\}$; that is, the lines you get by letting $x$ and $y$ vary.

Comment: @WilliamElliot Yes, that is what I meant. Sorry about the poor/lazy notation.

Comment: In the style of Georg Cantor we can prove the existence of such lines without giving a single example.  Let S be the set of lines parallel to a given line. Each rational point lies on just one member of S, and there are countably many rational points, But S is uncountable, and the members  of S are pair-wise disjoint, so there are uncountably many members of  S that contain no rational points.

Comment: @jackson5.  Write {pi}xR.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a very simple example.  Let $\alpha$ be any irrational number.  Then the line consisting of points of the form $(t,t+\alpha)$ contains no rational points.  Indeed, if both $t$ and $t+\alpha$ were rational, then $(t+\alpha)-t=\alpha$ would be rational as well, which is a contradiction.

More generally, any non-vertical line is the graph of a function $f(t)=at+b$ for some $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$.  If such a graph contains a rational point, that means there are rational numbers $q$ and $t$ such that $q=at+b$, or $b=q-at$.  For any fixed $a$, there are only countably many numbers of the form $q-at$ for $q,t\in\mathbb{Q}$, so for all but countably many choices of $b$, the graph of $f(t)=at+b$ contains no rational points.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, consider the diagonal segment emanating from $(\sqrt{2}, 1).$

Answer (score 2):

You need to take two $\mathbb Q$ linearly independent irrational numbers in $\mathbb R$, $x$ and $y$ (I think $\pi$ and $e$ would do the trick), and look at something like $t(x,y)+(a,b)$ where $a$ and $b$ are rational.

Since $\mathbb Q$ is a field (you can add, subtract, multiply AND divide rational numbers), you can think of $\mathbb R$ as a $\mathbb Q$ vector space! It's infinite dimensional, but there are still bases. There are certainly numbers which are linearaly independent, i.e. there is $x$ and $y$ in $\mathbb R$ such that there are no non-zero rational numbers $a,b$ such that $ax + by = 0$, which has to be the case if you are going to get a rational point on $t(x,y)$.

Comment: That $\mathbb R$ has a $\mathbb Q$-basis is *a lot* stronger than that it has two linearly independent vectors. (One of these requires the axiom of choice, the other just requires you show that there exists an irrational number)

Answer (score 1):

Consider the graph of $x+y=\pi$.